# Adding variables in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried looking here for an answer but didn't find anything.

I'm trying to do this (taken from [objectmentor.com](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/xpepisode.htm)):
[image]

So far, I've got this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm and 0mm]

\def \bigside {15}
\def \smallside {5}
\def \unit {mm}

\tikzset{holder/.style={draw, fill=white, font=\bfseries, minimum size=\bigside \unit, rectangle}}
\tikzset{derecha/.style={draw, fill=white, minimum size=\smallside \unit, rectangle}}

\node[holder] at (0,0) {5};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*1 \unit},0) {14};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*2 \unit},0) {29};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*3 \unit},0) {49};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*4 \unit},0) {60};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*5 \unit},0) {61};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*6 \unit},0) {77};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*7 \unit},0) {97};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*8 \unit},0) {117};
\node[holder] at ({\bigside*9 \unit},0) {133};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That draws the big rectangles. Now I'm trying to draw the small rectangles (I'll start with those that have numbers) on the top right corner.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
\node[derecha] at ({\smallside + \bigside*0 \unit }, {\smallside \unit }) {4};
\node[derecha] at ({\smallside + \bigside*1 \unit }, {\smallside \unit }) {5};
% etc
```

If I put the result of `(\smallside + \bigside* i)` it works (i.e. 5 mm, 20mm, 35mm, etc.), but this doesn't.

If I use the default units (cm) and don't put the `\unit` it also works:

```
\node[derecha] at ({\smallside + \bigside*0 }, {\smallside }) {4};
\node[derecha] at ({\smallside + \bigside*1}, {\smallside  }) {5};
```

This also works, but it's a pain in the ... stomach

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\posa{\smallside + \bigside*0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\posb{\smallside + \bigside*1}
% etc
\node[derecha] at ({\posa \unit }, {\smallside \unit }) {4};
\node[derecha] at ({\posb \unit }, {\smallside \unit }) {5};
% etc
```

So, how can I make this work?

Comment: `5+15mm` will evaluated to `5pt+15mm` by TikZ. But: instead of using `\unit` simply set the *x* and *y* vector `mm`: `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm,node distance=0mm and 0mm]`

Comment: Excelent, now I don't know which answer is better. If you put it as an answer, I'll see later which one was the best for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comment, something like `5+15mm` will be interpreted as `5pt+15mm`(source: somewhere in the PGF manual). But you can change the coordinate system to use the unit `mm` with `x=1mm, y=1mm`, then you are able to use `5 + 15` which translate to `20mm`.

Toscho’s solution (with a `path picture` instead of a separate node) would then look like Code A.

---

Though you didn’t asked for, I created a slightly more powerful `holder` key that accepts a parameter in the form of `<val1>:<val2>` or `<val1>:<val2>:<val3>` (for the last node). You can also give no argument at all, then `:` will be used (i.e. no contents but a box in the right-upper corner). The `<vali>` can also be one of `x`, `X` or `/`  which will draw a black box or a black triangle (this may not be the best approach).

I haven’t realized that it is also possible to only have a black box, this will need to be input as `:X`. The `holder` stuff can be improved so that you can use `holder=X` if needed.

The `chains` library helps us to easily place the nodes.

### Code A

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
 use unit/.code={
   \def\myUnit{#1}%
   \pgfkeysalso{x=1#1,y=1#1}%
 },
 set sizes/.code args={#1and#2}{\def\bigside{#1}\def\smallside{#2}},
 ?/.style={
   path picture={
     \node[dereche,anchor=north east] at (path picture bounding box.north east) {#1};
   }
 }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=0mm and 0mm,
  use unit=mm,
  set sizes=15 and 5,
  box/.style={
    shape=rectangle, % the default
    draw,
    fill=white
  },
  holder/.style={
    box,
    minimum size=\bigside\myUnit
  },
  dereche/.style={
    box,
    minimum size=\smallside\myUnit
  }
  ]

    \node[holder, ?=4] (n1) at (0,0) {5};
    \node[holder, ?=5] (n2) at (\bigside*1,0) {14};
    \node[holder] (n3)  at (\bigside*2,0) {29};
    \node[holder] (n4)  at (\bigside*3,0) {49};
    \node[holder] (n5)  at (\bigside*4,0) {60};
    \node[holder] (n6)  at (\bigside*5,0) {61};
    \node[holder] (n7)  at (\bigside*6,0) {77};
    \node[holder] (n8)  at (\bigside*7,0) {97};
    \node[holder] (n9)  at (\bigside*8,0) {117};
    \node[holder] (n10) at (\bigside*9,0) {133};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code B

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                chains}
\makeatletter
\def\qrr@bowl@X{x}
\def\qrr@bowl@slash{/}
\tikzset{
 use unit/.code={
   \def\myUnit{#1}%
   \pgfkeysalso{x=1#1,y=1#1}% we don't really need this anymore
 },
 set sizes/.code={\def\bigside{#1}\def\smallside{(#1/3)}},
 box/.style={
   shape=rectangle, % the default
   draw,
   outer sep=+0pt,
 },
 holder/.style={
   box,
   minimum size=\bigside\myUnit,
   font=\bfseries\Large,
   text height=+2em,
   qrr@holder=#1,
 },
 holder/.default=:,
 mini/.style={
   box,
   minimum width=\smallside*1\myUnit,
   minimum height=\smallside*1\myUnit,
   outer sep=+0pt,
%   text height=,
%   font=,
   qrr@mini=#1
 },
 mini/.default=,
 qrr@mini/.code=%
  \lowercase{\def\pgf@tempa{#1}}%
  \ifx\pgf@tempa\qrr@bowl@X
    \pgfkeysalso{qrr@X}%
  \else\ifx\pgf@tempa\qrr@bowl@slash
      \pgfkeysalso{qrr@slash}%
    \else
      \pgfkeysalso{label={center:{#1}}}% the labels also needs [font=,text height=] if used with a path picture
    \fi
  \fi,
 qrr@holder/.code args={#1:#2}{%
   \pgfutil@in@:{#2}%
   \ifpgfutil@in@
     \pgfkeysalso{qrr@@holder={#1:#2}}%
   \else
     \pgfkeysalso{qrr@@holder={:#1:#2}}%
   \fi
 },
 qrr@@holder/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{% we could have used simple rectangles instead of nodes ...
%   path picture={
   append after command={%
     \pgfextra
      \begingroup
%     \node[mini=#3, anchor=north east] (@qrr@) at (path picture bounding box.north east)            {};
        \node[mini=#3, anchor=east] (@qrr@) at ([yshift=-\smallside*.5\myUnit]\tikzlastnode.north east)                {};
        \tikzset{mini/.append style={left=+0pt of @qrr@}}
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
          \node[mini=#2, shape=rectangle, draw=none, minimum width={(\bigside-\smallside)*1\myUnit}]                    {};
        \else
          \node[mini=#2, minimum width={(\bigside-\smallside-\smallside)*1\myUnit}]            (@qrr@) {};
          \node[mini=#1, shape=rectangle, draw=none, minimum width={(\bigside-\smallside-\smallside)*1\myUnit}]         {};
        \fi
      \endgroup
     \endpgfextra
   }
 },
 qrr@X/.style={fill=black},
 qrr@slash/.style={path picture={\fill[black](path picture bounding box.south west)-|(path picture bounding box.north east)--cycle;}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  use unit=mm,
  set sizes=15,
  % just for fun a little bubblier:
  mini/.append style={shape=circle},
  holder/.append style={rounded corners=\smallside*.5\myUnit}
  ]
  \begin{scope}[start chain=going right, holder/.append style={on chain}, node distance=+0pt]
    \node[holder=1:4]     {5};
    \node[holder=4:5]    {14};
    \node[holder=6:/]    {29};
    \node[holder=5:/]    {49};
    \node[holder= :x]    {60};
    \node[holder=0:1]    {61};
    \node[holder=7:/]    {77};
    \node[holder=6:/]    {97};
    \node[holder= :X]   {117};
    \node[holder=2:/:6] {133};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Output (bubbly)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will take a while to fully understand but the result is awesome. One last question, I'm having each tikz-picture in a separate tex file and then I `\input{}` them. It's ok to put the `makeatletter ... makeatother` part inside the document so I can directly input the file and I don't have to touch the master?

Comment: @Nico You’re welcome. I have updated the code a little bit. Instead of a `path picture` I use now a `append after command` which has the advantage that nodes used inside there do not inherit any styles from the `holder` node but the disadvantage that the stuff will be drawn *behind* the `holder` node (so a `fill` shouldn’t be used). Another solution would be to use simple paths (for rectangles, triangles and whatnot) instead of the `mini` nodes.

Comment: I have some odd behaviour... The bold numbers look crappy. If I comment the `qrr@holder=#1,` in the holder style, it looks good. I'm using the last edit, commented out the circle and rounded corners, I also used `\large` instead of `\Large`. Check out what I mean here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63456043/normal.png, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63456043/odd.png

Comment: @Nico I can’t really see an issue. Maybe there is a difference in aliasing, but hardly visible even at full zoom.

Answer (score 4):

Use node names and anchors:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm and 0mm]

\def \bigside {15}
\def \smallside {5}
\def \unit {mm}

\tikzset{holder/.style={draw, fill=white, font=\bfseries, minimum size=\bigside \unit, rectangle}}
\tikzset{derecha/.style={draw, fill=white, minimum size=\smallside \unit, rectangle}}

\node[holder](n1) at (0,0) {5};
\node[holder](n2) at ({\bigside*1 \unit},0) {14};
\node[holder](n3) at ({\bigside*2 \unit},0) {29};
\node[holder](n4) at ({\bigside*3 \unit},0) {49};
\node[holder](n5) at ({\bigside*4 \unit},0) {60};
\node[holder](n6) at ({\bigside*5 \unit},0) {61};
\node[holder](n7) at ({\bigside*6 \unit},0) {77};
\node[holder](n8) at ({\bigside*7 \unit},0) {97};
\node[holder](n9) at ({\bigside*8 \unit},0) {117};
\node[holder](n10) at ({\bigside*9 \unit},0) {133};

\node[derecha,anchor=north east] at (n1.north east) {4};
\node[derecha,anchor=north east] at (n2.north east) {5};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to work, the first time I tried to put the "holders" with `right=of` but had some problems so I abandoned the idea.

Answer (score 2):

To place the nodes automatically, I would use a `chain`. In the example below, to be considered as a starting point, I also defined some shapes: `bowling` and `bowlings` the first one is basically a rectangle with a little square in the upper right corner, and the second one adds to bowling a filling of half the square (to be used for spares).

Here's an example showing the two defined shapes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,chains,shapes}

\def\smallside{10pt}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{bowling}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
\backgroundpath{%
% store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
\southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
% compute corner of little square
\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-\smallside
\pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-\smallside
% construct main path
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathclose
% add little dquare
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
}
}

\pgfdeclareshape{bowlings}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
\backgroundpath{%
% store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
\southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
% compute corner of little square
\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-\smallside
\pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-\smallside
% construct main path
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathclose
% add little square
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% fill half the square
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfsetfillcolor{black}
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,bowling,minimum size=30pt]  {};
\node[draw,bowlings,minimum size=30pt,xshift=40pt]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The long part is to define the shapes, but once thay have been defined, the code for the actual figure is really simple:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
start chain,
every node/.style={on chain,outer sep=0pt},
node distance=0pt
]
\node[holder]  (a) {5};
\node[holder] (b) {14};
\node[holder] (c) {29};
\node[holder] (d) {49};
\node[spare] (e) {60};
\node[spare] (f) {61};
\node[holder] (g) {77};
\node[holder] (h) {97};
\node[holder] (i){117};
\node[holder] (j) {133};
\end{scope}
\foreach \name/\numero in {a/1,b/5,c/6,d/5,g/8,h/1,i/6,j/4}
  \node[derecha,anchor=north east] at (\name.north east) {\numero};
\foreach \name/\numero in {e/3,f/6}
  \node[derecha,anchor=north east,xshift=-\smallside] at (\name.north east) {\numero};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,chains,shapes}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{bowling}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
\backgroundpath{%
% store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
\southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
% compute corner of little square
\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-\smallside
\pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-\smallside
% construct main path
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathclose
% add little dquare
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
}
}

\pgfdeclareshape{bowlings}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
\backgroundpath{%
% store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
\southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
% compute corner of little square
\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-\smallside
\pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-\smallside
% construct main path
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathclose
% add little square
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% fill half the square
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfsetfillcolor{black}
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
}
}
\makeatother

\def\bigside{15mm}
\def\smallside{5mm}

\tikzset{holder/.style={bowling,draw, fill=white, font=\bfseries, minimum size=\bigside}}
\tikzset{spare/.style={bowlings,draw, fill=white, font=\bfseries, minimum size=\bigside}}
\tikzset{derecha/.style={minimum size=\smallside}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
start chain,
every node/.style={on chain,outer sep=0pt},
node distance=0pt
]
\node[holder]  (a) {5};
\node[holder] (b) {14};
\node[holder] (c) {29};
\node[holder] (d) {49};
\node[spare] (e) {60};
\node[spare] (f) {61};
\node[holder] (g) {77};
\node[holder] (h) {97};
\node[holder] (i){117};
\node[holder] (j) {133};
\end{scope}
\foreach \name/\numero in {a/1,b/5,c/6,d/5,g/8,h/1,i/6,j/4}
  \node[derecha,anchor=north east] at (\name.north east) {\numero};
\foreach \name/\numero in {e/3,f/6}
  \node[derecha,anchor=north east,xshift=-\smallside] at (\name.north east) {\numero};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]